# encrypted time machine backups to a single external hdd from more than one mbp

Tags: time-machine, external-disk, encryption

I am planning to get a external HDD for time machine backups for 2 macbook pros.

- Can both of them backup to the same HDD
- Can the disk be time machine encrypted and still be accessible to both?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that. Just divide the disk into two partitions and you are done.

The [*Disk Utility*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Utility) app provided by Apple with your Mac can be used to create partitions.